# При освобождении памяти от указателей на массивы вылетает ошибка: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(phead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "float.h"

using namespace std;


void decShellSort(float *arr, int size)              //Сортировка по убыванию
{
int step = size / 2;    //инициализируем шаг.

while (step > 0)    //пока шаг не 0
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (size - step); i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        //будем идти начиная с i-го элемента
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] < arr[j + step])
        //пока не пришли к началу массива
        //и пока рассматриваемый элемент больше
        //чем элемент находящийся на расстоянии шага
            {
                //меняем их местами
                float temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + step];
                arr[j + step] = temp;
                j--; 
            }
    }
    step = step / 2;      //уменьшаем шаг
}    
}

float getMin(float *arr, int cc)
{
float min = FLT_MAX;
for(int i=0;i<cc; i++)
    if(arr[i]<min) min = arr[i]; 
return min;
}

void printMatrix(float **arr, int rc, int cc)
{
for(int i=0;i<rc; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<cc; j++)
        cout<< setprecision(2) << fixed << arr[i][j] <<"    ";
    cout<<"\n";
}
cout<<"\n";
}

void setMDim(int *dim)
{
*dim = 0;
while(*dim <= 1)
{
    cin>>*dim;
    //Если ввели меньше минимальной допустимой 
    if(*dim <= 1) cout<<"Вы ввели недопустимую размерность матрицы.\n"    <<"Попробуйте еще раз...\n\n";
}
cout<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"russian_russia");

//Ввод размерности матрицы
int M;                                          //кол-во строк
int N;                                          //кол-во столбцов

cout << "Введите кол-во строк M матрицы:\n";
setMDim(&M);
cout << "Введите кол-во столбцов N матрицы:\n";
setMDim(&N);

//Создание матрицы целых чисел
float **matrix = new float *[M];    //создаем строки
for(int i=0; i<M; i++)          
    matrix[i] = new float [N];  //создаем столбцы

//Инициализация матрицы случайными числами
for(int i=0; i<M; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = (float)(rand()%9)/(float)7+(float)(rand()%9);

//Вывод матрицы
printMatrix(matrix,M,N);

//Создание массива для минимумов матрицы
float *minArr = new float [M];

//Поиск минимума в каждой строке и заполнение ими массива
for(int i=0; i<M; i++)
{
    minArr[i] = getMin(matrix[i],N);
}

//Сортировка массива минимумов по убыванию
decShellSort(minArr, M);

    //создание второй матрицы для копирования из первой
float **matrix2 = new float *[M];   
for(int i=0; i<M; i++)  
    matrix2[i] = new float [N];

    //Сортируем строки матрицы
for(int i=0; i<M; i++)
{
    float *arr = new float [N];
    float num = getMin(matrix[i],N);
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        if(minArr[j] == num)
        {
            matrix2[j] = matrix[i];
            minArr[j] = NULL;
            break;
        }
    delete []arr; 
}

printMatrix(matrix2,M,N);

//Освобождение памяти
delete []minArr;

for(int i = 0; i<M; i++){
    delete []matrix[i];
    delete []matrix2[i];
}
delete []matrix;
delete []matrix2;


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

При освобождении памяти на какой-то итерации цикла в этом месте: delete []matrix[i]; 
вылетает ошибка: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(phead->nBlockUse)

Кто подскажет, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательно на эту строку

```
matrix2[j] = matrix[i];
```

здесь не копируется строка. Здесь копируется просто указатель. Поэтому комментирование строки

```
delete []matrix2;
```

решает проблему падения. Но это не решит другую, скрытую пробелему - утечки памяти. Дело в том, что для строк matrix2 память выдеяется, но в вышеприведенной строке затирается указатель - на лицо утечка.

Вывод - либо пишите красиво копирование строки массива, либо перейдите на нормальный с++ - используйте std::vector/std::array.

два варианта скопировать

старый добрый си

```
memcpy(matrix2[j], matrix[i], M*sizeof(float));
```

банальное копирование в лоб

```
for (int t = 0; t < M; t++) {
  matrix2[j][t] = matrix[i][t];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! изменил, работает как надо.